# Change text of headline when cloning element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors

Im cloning a section of a form and have hit a couple stumbling blocks. I am able to clone the form and update each form element's name attribute and have 2 issues.
Here is my code:

```
function newObservation() {
    var len = $('.observation').length;
    var $html = $('.observationTemplate').clone();

    $html.find($('.observationTitle')[0].text("Observation -" + len));
    $html.find('[name=audit-observation-category]')[0].name="audit-observation-category" + len;
    $html.find('[name=audit-observation-notes]')[0].name="audit-observation-notes" + len;
    $html.find('[name=audit-observation-recommendation]')[0].name="audit-observation-recommendation" + len;
    $html.find('[name=audit-observation-severity]')[0].name="audit-observation-severity" + len;
    $html.find('[name=audit-observation-person]')[0].name="audit-observation-person" + len;
    $html.find('[name=audit-observation-date]')[0].name="audit-observation-date" + len;

    return $html.html();
}
```

I cannot seem to update the  's text. I need to add the same number to it as each form element gets. So the first clone would say "Observation - 1". Using both .text and .html and get "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'text' "

I also can't get the syntax right to update the elemen'ts ID as well.

```
$html.find('[name=audit-observation-category]')[0].{name="audit-observation-category" + len.id="audit-observation-category" + len};
```

and others fail each time.

Any adive is much appreciate! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `eq(0)` instead of `[0]` which returns the DOM element and which is not a jquery object with `text` method on it:

```
$('.observationTitle:eq(0)').text("Observation -" + len);
```

And if you are trying to set the id of the element you could do:

```
var name = "audit-observation-category" + len;
$html.find('[name=audit-observation-category]').attr({name:name,  id:name );
```

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick for the title issue. Is there any way to start the count at 1 instead of 0? Also, do you have any insight into changing the ID's as well as the element's name?

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign What do you mean by count starting as 1. Can you give an example. Do you mean for the first one. You could do `var len = $('.observation').length + 1;` So incase of no elements initially it will give you 1 for the first one instead of 0

Comment: Yes, that was it. Just added +2 and it worked as I wanted. Thanks again.

Comment: Still working on the second part, modifying the name and id attribute. Will mark as correct when I get that working.

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign This is where providing a simple Fiddle would help... :)

Comment: Wish i could, extenuating circumstances. Just need some way to add the ID along with the name in the format I had shown originally.

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign The example i have shown will add it. But I have no idea what are you trying unless you prepare a fiddle to show it.

Comment: with what you wrote, i would have to create a var name for each element. Im trying to increment the id attribute as well as the name. what I have currently only increments the name attribute.

Comment: been trying  to make a fiddle, works locally not on jsfiddle though. gets msie error

Comment: fwiw here is fiddle, can't get rid of errors in the jQuery code though (not mine) http://jsfiddle.net/auBMZ/

Comment: Great stuff man, thank you. so [0] doesn't work with attributes. Again, thank you.

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign `[0]` gives you DOM element, but `attr` is on jquery object. SO you need to do `:eq(0)` But actually in your case you dont need to do it since cloning from the remplate has only one such element so you can directly do `.attr` on the jq object as well.